# XNA - how can i increase my sprite speed

Tags: c#, xna, game-physics

SO i'm a beginner in programming and i need help with how to make my sprites speed increase (Add a sprint feature)

i  have tried myself but i failed, if someone could explain how i could do it i would be very grateful.

All i want done is if i press the right trigger on my Xbox controller while moving my left thumb stick right change the speed from 4 to 6.

This is the thing i tried , i realized this wouldn't work because it would just make the sprite move when i press he trigger.

```
if (pad1.Triggers.Right < 0.0f)
  position += new Vector2(-6, 0);

if (pad1.Triggers.Right >= 0.4f)
  position += new Vector2(6, 0);
```

I'm out of options so someone please help.

Comment: I'm guessing the number you want to change is -6 or 6 ? If it is check if both things are pressed If they are both pressed set it to 6 if it is not pressed then set it to 4.

Comment: sorry but how do i check 2 things at the same time

Comment: if (condition1 && condition2)

Comment: Right i have this so far                                            if (pad1.Triggers.Right < 1.0f && pad1.ThumbSticks.Left.X < 0.0f)
   position += new Vector2(-6, 0);
   else
if (pad1.ThumbSticks.Left.X < 0.0f)
position += new Vector2(-4, 0);

if (pad1.Triggers.Right < 1.0f && pad1.ThumbSticks.Left.X < 0.0f)
   position += new Vector2(6, 0);
   else
if (pad1.ThumbSticks.Left.X >= 0.4f)
position += new Vector2(4, 0);                                         so when i go left its speed is 4 and when i then press the trigger it goes to 6, all good.  then when i move right its moves at speed 6

Comment: Please edit your post above so I can read that easier.

Comment: this is what i have                                                            if (pad1.Triggers.Right < 1.0f && pad1.ThumbSticks.Left.X < 0.0f)            position += new Vector2(-6, 0);

Comment: Please edit your question above to include that so it is easier to read...

Comment: This would be easier https://www.mediafire.com/?t3ciuud55b91t7d

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamentally a physics problem. Adding a constant amount to the position is only going to move the sprite more. What you're probably looking for is a way to increase the velocity over brief a period of time which is known as acceleration.

```
const float AccelerationForce = 0.ff;
const float MaxAccelerationForce = 0.8f;;
static readonly Vector2 MaxAcceleration
    = new Vector2(MaxAccelerationForce, MaxAccelerationForce);
static readonly Vector2 Acceleration = new Vector2(AccelerationForce, 0);
static readonly Vector2 Deceleration = new Vector2(-AccelerationForce, 0);
Vector _currentAcceleration = new Vector2(0, 0);
Vector _currentVelocity = new Vector2(0, 0);

Vector2 Clamp(Vector2 value, Vector2 min, Vector2 max)
{
    var x = MathHelper.Clamp(value.X, min.X, max.X);
    var y = MathHelper.Clamp(value.Y, min.Y, max.Y);

    return new Vector2(x, y);
}

bool RequiresAcceleration(float currentForce)
{
    return currentForce >= AccelerationForce;
}

var currentForce = GetCurrentForce();
// Calculate whether we need to accelerate or decelerated
var acceleration = RequiresAcceleration(currentForce)
                       ? Acceleration
                       : Deceleration;
var newAcceleration = _currentAcceleration + acceleration;
// acceleration is bounded MaxAcceleration > _currentAcceleration > 0
_currentAcceleration = Clamp(newAcceleration, Vector2.Zero, MaxAcceleration);

_currentVelocity += _currentAcceleration;

// Code to move the player

if (pad1.Triggers.Right < 0.0f)
  position += _currentVelocity);

if (pad1.Triggers.Right >= 0.4f)
  position -= _currentVelocity;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve. Also editing a post is rather easy please edit posts rather than commenting with an update.

```
        if (pad1.Triggers.Right < 0)
            // This checks if left thumbstick is less than 0.
            // If it is less than zero it sets position.X += -6. 
            // If it is not less then it sets position.X += -4.
            position.X -= (pad1.ThumbSticks.Left.X < 0) ? 6 : 4;
        else if (pad1.Triggers.Right >= 0.4f) // shouldn't this be > 0.0f or > 0 ?
            // This is the same as above just in the right direction.
            position.X += (pad1.ThumbSticks.Left.X > 0) ? 6 : 4;
```

Comment: this code makes the sprite move right only if the trigger is pressed, and there is no left movement. P.S sorry for being a noob. EDIT: im on about  the code above

Comment: still not working the thumb stick doesn't do anything and when i press the  right trigger the sprite just moves right at the speed of 4

Comment: I need a better explanation to see what is wrong. 
When you press the right trigger only it should move left or right respectively. When you press the right trigger and the left it should speed up in the required direction.
How are you checking if it is not working ? Are you displaying the values so you can see them ?